# bitbake fails at the simplest recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Just installed `Yocto`. On a `morty` branch. Executed the following commands:

```
cd poky
source oe-init-build-env build-qemuarm
```

In `conf/local.conf` changed the name of the machine to `MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"`

Then executed the following:

```
$ bitbake core-image-minimal
Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1320 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: Execution of event handler 'sstate_eventhandler2' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/meta/classes/sstate.bbclass", line 1015, in sstate_eventhandler2(e=<bb.event.ReachableStamps object at 0x7fbc17f2e0f0>):
                 for l in lines:
    >                (stamp, manifest, workdir) = l.split()
                     if stamp not in stamps:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

ERROR: Command execution failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 101, in runAsyncCommand
    self.cooker.updateCache()
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 1658, in updateCache
    bb.event.fire(event, self.databuilder.mcdata[mc])
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 201, in fire
    fire_class_handlers(event, d)
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 124, in fire_class_handlers
    execute_handler(name, handler, event, d)
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 96, in execute_handler
    ret = handler(event)
  File "/home/some-user/projects/melp/poky/meta/classes/sstate.bbclass", line 1015, in sstate_eventhandler2
    (stamp, manifest, workdir) = l.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

It looks like it is a `python` error. Does anyone know what is the issue? Am I using the wrong version?

Here is the output of `python --version`

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check your host matches [Yocto requirements](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#intro-requirements)?

Answer (score 2):

You realise that Morty is 18 months old and in a few weeks will be longer supported right?

Anyway, looks like the `sstate-cache/` somehow is corrupted.  Delete your `tmp/` and `sstate-cache/` directories and try again.

Comment: Why did you reproach him for working on Morty ? Always working on latest version is idyllic

Comment: deleting tmp/ directory is too time consuming imho, works directory may not corrupted plus is the biggest generated file is placed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

I go through this post along with [bitbake failed](https://community.toradex.com/t/bitbake-failed-with-errors/7490) and [exicution of event handler "check-sanity-eventhandler" faild](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/exicution-of-event-handler-quot-check-sanity-eventhandler-quot/td-p/413897)

Nothing worked for me. Even I disable the encryption [How to Disable Home Folder Encryption](https://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/)  of home folder still it did not work for me.

basically, I was using Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS and pocky dunfell branch.

I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS in virtual machine and used pocky dunfell branch. It worked for me.

In another Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS machine I added this command in conf/local.conf file

```
BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER = "OEEquivHash"
```

`BB_HASHSERVE = "auto"`
`BB_HASHSERVE_UPSTREAM = "hashserv.yocto.io:8687"`
`SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "file://.* https://sstate.yoctoproject.org/all/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH"`

And it worked for me.